# Как предотвратить открытие новой страницы при переходе по ссылке?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы на сайте при переходе по ссылке она не открывалась в новой вкладке, а оставалась на той же странице?

Comment: @Лиля 25, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: <a href="" target="_blank">в новом окне</a>
<a href="">в том же окне</a>

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы предотвратить открытие новых вкладок на любом сайте нужно поставить расширение браузера. Я использую это в некоторых проектах
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/0iOD0wXwIbnlVg

Оно основано на этом:

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/death-to-blank/gneobebnilffgkejpfhlgkmpkipgbcno

Comment: Если расширение существует официально, лучше дать ссылку на него, а не на личную шару, которая может быть воспринята как спам.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ добавлял некоторые моменты сам в это расширение, добавил ссылку на оригинал

Answer (score -1):

Это дефолтное поведение, для него достаточно просто написать саму ссылку.